# cordova build android error : The system cannot find the path specified. Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

I am very new to Ionic2 app development and am trying to build an Android app with it. I want to run the app in Visual Studio emulator and am getting the below error while running 'cordova build android' command.
Please help with it!
Thanks in advance!

```
**C:\Devlopment ionic\sample\sampleapp>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\d.dutta.chowdhury\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1**
```

[image]

Comment: have you installed cordova? what does `cordova requirements` give?

Comment: yes I have. It gave this :                                                      
                                                                                            
 Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-25,android-24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,android-23
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle

Comment: I have also set the ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME variables correctly. Don't know why I am getting this error! :(

Comment: `C:\Program Files\` I havent used windows for some time.. can you double check if space in path name is valid?

Comment: go to `https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html` download the sdk tools for windows unzip it and paste it here `C:\Users\[YOU USER NAME]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools` and it will work

Comment: @Deblina found any solution?

Comment: [you can this answer to solve your query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322400/cordova-error-cmd-command-failed-with-exit-code-1)

Answer (score 4):

just downgrade your android version to 5

```
cordova platform rm android
```

then

```
cordova platform add android@~5
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and used this command to build project to display entire log with which it is failing,

```
cordova build -d
```

it will show gradle path ,sdk path being used to run.
In my case, gradle path was not present.

Answer (score 0):

Running this script worked for me

https://github.com/erobertson42/cordova-plugin-xapkreader/blob/cordova-9/scripts/before_install.js

Here's the code.
You'll have to run `npm i fs-extra q`

```
let fse = require('fs-extra');
let q = require('q');

module.exports = function(context) {
    const deferral = q.defer();
    let target = 'platforms/android/cordova/lib/plugin-build.gradle';

    console.log('scripts/before_install: fixing gradle');

    fse.readFile(target, 'utf8').then((data) => {
        // replace deprecated "compile" configurations with "implementation"
        data = data.replace(/debugCompile (project\(.*)\,.*(\))\n\s*releaseCompile.*/g, 'implementation $1)');

        // replace old Java 1_6 variables with 1_8
        data = data.replace(/(JavaVersion\.VERSION_1)_6/g, '$1_8');

        // fix "cdvCompileSdkVersion" and "cdvBuildToolsVersion" undefined variables
        data = data.replace(/\/\/ GENERATED FILE! DO NOT EDIT!/, match => `${match}
ext {
    apply from: '../../CordovaLib/cordova.gradle'
    cdvCompileSdkVersion = privateHelpers.getProjectTarget()
    cdvBuildToolsVersion = privateHelpers.findLatestInstalledBuildTools()
}
`);

        return fse.writeFile(target, data, 'utf8').then(() => {
            console.log('scripts/before_install: done!');
            deferral.resolve();
        });
    }).catch((e) => {
        deferral.reject('scripts/before_install: error ' + e);
    });

    return deferral.promise;
};
```