# Cordova - Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

when we try to run android it always give error on new created project on cordova

```
D:\Android\Theplug>cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=D:\Android\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_111
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

Cordova requirements:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed Google Inc.:Google APIs:24,Google Inc.:Google APIs:23,
Google Inc.:Google APIs:22,Google Inc.:Google APIs:21,android-25,android-24,android-23,
android-22,android-21
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
```

Comment: does `java -version` work?

Comment: @suraj yes its works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just downgrade your android version to 5

---

```
cordova platform rm android
```

then

```
cordova platform add android@~5
```

---

it worked for me.